# Suggestions for building sql strings with jdbctemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I currently have this:

```
MyObject myObject = getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject("select * from my_objects where id = ?",
                new Object[]{new Integer(id)},
                new MyObjectRowMapper());
```

Now in my method I want to pass an enumeration:

```
SortOrder.ASC
SortOrder.DESC
```

So it will either be:

```
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

or

```
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

So inside the sql string, do I just add another '?' or do I have to build up the string like:

```
"select * from abc ORDER BY ID " + sortOrder;
```

Is there a preferred way?

Comment: String concatenation of SQL queries is risky, the `sortOrder` must be sanitized **very** well.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz not in my case since it is done on the backend only, not via input from the end user.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the second way. A prepared statement isn't just a "query-replace placeholders by the String I pass". All parameters must be typed values to insert into the syntax tree generated from the query. You can't pass a portion of a query as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the query in `PreparedStatements` so you can not use ? for `asc` or `desc`. I think concatenation is the simplest way you can use.

Comment: I must correct it, as far as I know most of the DBMSes (Oracle, MySQL, ...) don't support prepared statement places-holders in query structure. I'm not sure maybe some support.